# Retrieve file properties in ios

Tags: ios, pdf

I want to retrieve Following `attributes` from pdf file.

- Title
- Author
- Subject
- Keyword
- Created Date
- Modified Date
- Application

So far i extracted created date and modified date using `NSFileManager`. Is there any method to get this attribute in ios.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

This is the pictue i take from my mac. These are the infromation i want to extract.

Comment: If you would had searched on Google u would've gotten the result… everything u can do with a [file is given here](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/)

Comment: Most of those properties are metadata in the PDF file. You will need to parse the PDF to get that info. See the "Quartz 2D Programming Guide". There is a whole section on reading/parsing PDF files.

Comment: These information show in file info in my mac. so there should some way to extract in ios.

Comment: And this information common for every file. Because of that i cant extract from Quartz 2d

Comment: What do you mean every file has these attributes? That is not true at all. And where on your Mac do you see this info for every file?

Comment: The info under the "More Info" section is meta data from within the PDF. It is not info you will find for all files. You won't even get that info for all PDFs. Again, see my first comment.

Comment: Your correct I found the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51079/discussion-between-hasintha-and-rmaddy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGPDFDocumentRef _pdfDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(fileURL));
CGPDFDictionaryRef infoDic  = CGPDFDocumentGetInfo(_pdfDocRef);
```

It show following data,

```
key = Title
key = Creator
key = Author
key = Producer
key = Trapped
key = CreationDate
key = ModDate
```